# Uninstall clearcase 7.0.1.8 from the command line

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing, clearcase, clearquest

Is there an option to uninstall clearcase 7.0.1.8 through the command line, i want ot make it silent uninstallation using a `batch` script, and i want to uninstall ClearQuest 7.0.1.9 as wll through the command line.
Do i need to rebbot after each uninstallation?

Answer (score 0):

There are [silent uninstall response files for ClearCase 7.1.x all the way to 8.x](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21376355)

But ClearCase 7.0 (around 2007!) might not benefit from those.

- [Windows CC 7.0 has a silent installation procedure](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21179647)
- [Linux has a manual uninstallation process](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21257486) that you can try and script.

Comment: The thing is that i can't find the `clearcase.msi` file

Comment: @user3502786 so you are on Windows? I am sure the IBM support can provide that file if you have lost it.

Comment: I found the `clearcase.msi` but i have 2 files in the installation directory:
1) `1033_ClearCase.msi`
2) `1041_ClearCase.msi`
Which one should i use?

Comment: @user3502786 https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000013897430: The MSI's with the different numbers are for the different languages. 1033
is English, 1041 is Japanese, etc. So... 1033 in your case, I would presume.

Comment: @user3502786 I don't know exactly, but I suspect there would be an uninstall msi file as well.

Comment: @user3502786 for instance: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21193899

Comment: Thanks! I'll have more questions in the next few days because I'm migrating to CC8